# How to test Node redirection with Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I am using Jest to test my Node REST API.

The problem I have currently is that when I try testing my POST routes, I always receive a status code of 302 due to `res.redirect("/")`.

Example of my POST route:

```
app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      let username = 'example'

      ...
      return res.redirect("/");

    } catch (error) {
       return res.redirect("/");
    }
  });
```

jest test file:

```
'use strict';
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('./index');
...
describe('Test', () => {

   test('POST /login', () => {
       return request(app)
             .post('/login')
             .set('username','example')
             .expect(?)

    });

});
```

How can I test that the page has redirected successfully?

Comment: The code you're testing doesn't make sense. A redirect is neither a 2xx nor 5xx response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect), you can specify a response code as such:

```js
res.redirect(301, 'http://example.com')
```

The docs state "If not specified, status defaults to “302 “Found”."

**Edit:** HTTP codes [301 and 302](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) indicate successful redirection; 301 is permanent and 302 is temporary. Both are "successful" as far as a computer is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

I assert the `response.headers.location` for redirection location. This way I can write test cases by mocking a single class function that causes different redirections.

```
test('Should handle "/redirectUri"', async () => {
  const exchangeForAuthTokenSpy = jest.spyOn(
    OAuth.prototype,
    'exchangeForAuthToken',
  )
  exchangeForAuthTokenSpy.mockResolvedValue({
    success: true,
    access_token: 'access_token',
  })
  const app = server('', AuthRoutes)
  const res = await request(app).get('/redirectUri?code=code&state=state')
  expect(exchangeForAuthTokenSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  expect(exchangeForAuthTokenSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('code', 'state')
  expect(res.status).toEqual(301)
  expect(res.headers.location).toContain(
    '/callback?code=200&token=access_token',
  )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is late, but could help someone. You can test like below

```
it('redirection test', function (redirect) {
        request(app)
            .get('/url')
            .expect(302, redirect) 
});
```